# Can't install Android ADT plugin in Eclipse - "error occurred while uninstalling"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Can anybody help get me past this error when I hit "Finish" when I'm in "Install new software" with Android DDMS and Development Tools in Eclipse 3.5.2? What's it trying to uninstall?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what it's trying to uninstall?

Comment: I was hoping someone had encountered and resolved the same problem. The full error details are: "'Install' has encountered a problem. An error occurred while uninstalling
  session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.apache.commons.lang 2.3.0.v200803061910 --> [R]org.apache.commons.lang 2.3.0.v201005080501, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
  String index out of range: 0
  String index out of range: 0"

Answer (score 1):

Run Eclipse as Administrator, and try installing the ADT. This is a common issue on Windows 7 I have noticed, so don't worry too much about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Disable AVG Antivirus or any antivirus and then... you can go on....

Comment: Well, that was exactly my problem, disable the AVG firewall